# Keep the UI responsive in main thread, webBrowser_DocumentCompleted while waiting on the same line of code

Tags: c#, timer, webbrowser-control

I want to wait some time in webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted Event.
The reason is so that Webbrowser Document stream is well downloaded when next document is completed. 
I don't want to block the UI when i am waiting and i don't want upcomming Document_Completed_Events to be fired.

```
 private void FormTimer()
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.rolex.com/");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    }
    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadCount++;
        alarmCounter = 0;
        Task abc = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (alarmCounter < 5)
            {
                Thread.Yield();
            }
        });
        abc.Start();
        Task.WaitAny(abc);
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        alarmCounter++;
    }
```

The problem is that tick stops as it goes in DocumentCompletedEvent.Kindly help me understand the problem as  well as a good approach to deal with these soughts of situations.

**Update:**
This technique works ,by detaching the expected unwanted events and go for DoEvents() It will also keep the UI responsive as well as timer tick.

```
    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "\nDocument Started" + documentCount;
        alarmCounter = 0;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        //Do some work
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        while (alarmCounter < 3)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();            
        }
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;             
        richTextBox1.Text += "\nDocument Completed." + documentCount;
    }
```

Comment: Blocking the UI thread is always a bug.  No point in burning up a Task to delay code, just start a timer instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Glad you looked at my code ,I have updated my question ,that has solved the problem of  timer as well as kept the UI responsive using Application.DoEvents(). I guess that is a secure use?

Comment: Programmers tend to have odd interpretations of the word "secure".  The only good thing about DoEvents() is that it doesn't infect a machine, the user knows how to get rid of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Are you use Windows.Forms.Timer? You should know, what Windows.Forms.Timer executes in same thread with UI. So then you call Task.WaitAny you block thread and your timer stop worked.

Comment: so how can i do that without blocking the main thread ,solution ?

Comment: if you want Task to simple wait some time (your timer interval * 5), why you not just write Task abc = Task.Delay(desiredTime); abc.Start()?